# How to grab/capture images from usb camera with OpenCV using EmguCV at high FPS?

Tags: opencv, emgucv, frame-rate, usb-camera

I have [this usb camera](http://www.kayetoncctv.com/Product/Info/789?cid=%5B%20%20%22289%22,%20%20%22784%22%5D). I want to cature video at a high framerate. The manufacturer states that the camera is able to do 180 FSP @ resolution 640x480. I did check this and the camera indeed works (hardware is okay; check including usb and PC).

My problem is, that I can't successfully setup the camera to the needed settings. I use EmguCV.

```cs
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize the VideoCapture object for webcam (default camera index)
    capture = new VideoCapture(0);

    // Check if the capture object is opened successfully
    if (!capture.IsOpened)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to open webcam!");
        return;
    }

    //manufacturer specs.
    //1280x720 MJPG @90fps -> yes I get video @90 fps
    //960x540 MJPG @90fps  -> no video -- I read out FPS=1
    //640x480 MJPG @180fps -> no video -- I read out FPS=1
    //640x360 MJPG @180fps -> no video -- I read out FPS=1
    //424x240 MJPG @180fps -> no video -- I read out FPS=1
    //320x240 MJPG @180fps -> yes I get video BUT @30fps
    //320x180 MJPG @180fps -> yes I get video BUT @30fps

    //capture.Set(CapProp.FourCC, fourcc); // is equal to => 1196444237
    var fourcc = Convert.ToDouble(VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));

    capture.Set(CapProp.FrameWidth, 640);    
    capture.Set(CapProp.FrameHeight, 360);
    capture.Set(CapProp.Fps, Convert.ToDouble(180));
    capture.Set(CapProp.FourCC, fourcc); 

    RtxbxShow.Text += $"Camera is ready!\n";
    RtxbxShow.Text += $"Set in cam FPS: {capture.Get(CapProp.Fps)}\n";
    RtxbxShow.Text += $"Set in cam Width: {capture.Get(CapProp.FrameWidth)}\n";
    RtxbxShow.Text += $"Set in cam Height: {capture.Get(CapProp.FrameHeight)}\n";
}
```

I set the propertys like this and then right after that I read out the propertys.
In the comments you can see what I read out. For my desired setting of 640x480 @180 fps. I get back FPS of 1. Funny enough the 90Fps setting works. But I need 180Fps any ideas?

EDIT:
I could read out the settings from the camera with ffmpeg.
And I could record a video with this: .\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -video_size 640x480 -framerate 180 -i video="USB 2M GS camera" output.mp4

Comment: you need to set it to MJPG too

Comment: I added capture.Set(CapProp.FourCC, VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')); But It is still not working. If I read out the FourCC I get '22' ???

Comment: permute order of set() calls. put fourcc first or last

Comment: did not work :(.

Comment: use ffmpeg, enumerate all capture modes. perhaps your specific chosen frame rate isn't among some set of supported rates. you should also check (with ffmpeg) whether *something* can get that capture mode working. if ffmpeg can't do it, no point in suspecting opencv of being at fault.

Comment: What platform? There should be a way to explicitly select a concrete VideoIO backend when constructing/opening a `VideoCapture` instance. What each backend can do can differ quite significantly.

Comment: @Dan Masek: I do all my programming in windows. With VisualStudio C#. This time I used Winforms .NET 8.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I got it to work. I changed the code from original post in one line.

From:

```cs
capture = new VideoCapture(0);
```

To:

```cs
capture = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCapture.API.DShow);
```

To set the capture to a specific backend (DShow). I left it the whole time on auto. But that didn't do it.

[Look here for more Info](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/22a2a020-b8fc-4fd4-8c7f-6155f34ad93b.htm)

Thx